# webapp only, Track activity(last signin time) of a user of a Cognito userpool

Tags: node.js, web-applications, amazon-cognito, analytics, aws-pinpoint

In our webapp (**no mobile app**), we use *cognito userpools for authentication*.
There is a *use case to track the user login activity* so that we will want to send this details to an existing power BI tool. A backend cron job(perhaps a lambda) is expected to fetch user login activity, transform the data and feed BI tool.

I've come across amazon pinpoint and it seems to be a good fit. I've followed the instructions given in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-pinpoint-integration.html to configure cognito userpool to send data to pinpoint, but I could not see any metrics in pinpoint console. I'm not sure what went wrong. Beside to this, *I'm not sure whether I can query pinpoint to fetch activity of a given user, this is required because this data will be fed to power BI to generate some custom metrics*.

Further googling has taken me to web app analytics setting. Based on this it seems I'll have to write some code on my backend side. Beside to that **it talks about identity pool, which is additional**. Things started confusing me and turning to complex setup.

[image]

It seems I'm missing something, could someone share some light?

**Note**: backend is nodejs/typescript